# Como funciona o how-old.net?

Tags: microsoft

Sobre o site [how-old.net](http://how-old.net/) (detecção de faces em imagens, com retorno de dados sobre a pessoa, como: idade, sexo, etc):

- Como isso funciona?
- Qual sua utilidade?
- Quais técnicas utilizadas?
- Quais tecnologias utilizadas?
- Como utiliza-lo?

Comment: O que é how-old.net? De onde você tirou isso? De um um link para entendermos. Mostre o que você está tentando fazer, ou o que ta fazendo, do jeito que está sua pergunta e bastante difícil alguém lhe dar uma resposta objetiva e satisfatória , dentro dos [padrões de perguntas do SOpt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Segue o link: how-old.net

Comment: Paulo Costa, editei sua pergunta para tentar deixa-la mais clara e objetiva, dentro dos padrões do SOpt. Por favor verifique a mesma, se continua de acordo com o seus objetivos iniciais, e em caso de discordância sinta-se a vontande para editar ou desfazer minha edição, mais tente deixa-la respondível. (Desculpe por editar bruscamente seu post, mais ele seria fechado rapidamente) =D

Comment: Interessante seria entender o por quê que essa pergunta está sendo votada para fechar e essa tem quatro votos a favor: [Como funciona o recurso “Buscar por imagem semelhantes” do google?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61165/3117). Seria por que o outro AP disse que está querendo construir algo parecido e esse daqui não?

Comment: Achei a pergunta interessante, acredito que não existe problema no entendimento e pode contribuir no compartilhamento de conhecimento entre os membros tranquilamente. Já vi muitas outras questões no StackOverflow e essa não é nenhuma aberração. Vamos utilizar do bom senso, não é nenhuma pergunta que prejudique este fórum.

Comment: Votei por reabertura.

Comment: @Math, os 3 primeiros votos para fechar, era na [primeira versão da pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/61218/1), até esse ponto até eu tinha votado para fechar, mas depois da [resposta do hamboldt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61219/2998), entendi do que se tratava e resolvi tentar ajudar o AP, a melhorar a pergunta que até então não estava clara e muito subjetiva (no meu entendimento), então editei a pergunta, sugeri nos comentários que o AP verifica-se a minha edição e removi meu voto de fechamento. E agora votei para reabertura.

Comment: @Fernando ok, agora as duas estão abertas e com 4 votos a favor :) Temi que as duas fossem fechadas depois do meu comentário, rs.. mas aparentemente tudo correu bem. Vamos ver que respostas virão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente eles calculam os ângulos dos traços faciais das pessoas afim de determinar o padrão de rugas e outros traços, e com base nisso cogitar qual é a idade da pessoa. Você pode ver abaixo uma resposta mais completa de um membro do time de desenvolvimento do Bing que participou da criação do sistema, onde ele dá mais detalhes sobre o algorítimo:

- http://www.quora.com/How-does-how-old-net-work