# identificar formas geometricas basicas em imagem

Tags: processamento-de-imagens

Tenho que identificar e catalogar perfies geometricos.
como os das imagens a seguir:
As imagens serao sempre digitalizadas a preto e branco, e com o tamanho real. e serao sempre compostos de formas geometricas, como circunferencias, rectangulos, elipses...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é encontrar perfies similares, ou seja dado um outro perfil, buscar nos que tenho catalogados e apresenta-los  por nivel de similaridade.

Existe alguma forma de desenvolver um algoritmo para isto? por onde começo? links para documentaçao
Domino PHP;ASP^e C e tenho uma ideias de visual basic.

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. A sua pergunta é interessante, mas ela está bastante ampla. Vc diz que precisa "identificar e catalogar". Bom, pra começar, a parte de identificação já envolve um monte de coisas. Por exemplo, vc precisa segmentar as formas (separá-las do fundo da imagem). Depois, você precisa conseguir classificá-las em diferentes categorias (ou seja, realmente "identificar" cada forma). Eu diria pra vc começar focando na separação das formas. Edite a pergunta nesse sentido, fornecendo um exemplo concreto de imagem, ok?

Comment: Leia também as demais perguntas já existentes na tag [tag:processamento-de-imagens]. Já há muita coisa que pode ser útil pra vc.

Comment: Algumas perguntas que podem ser úteis no quesito da segmentação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12488/73, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124576/73, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105693/73. Algumas úteis no quesito classificação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40135/73, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61165/73

Comment: Votei pra fechar de novo (após o meu voto ter expirado e passado o tempo de espera... #bummer) porque do jeito que está a pergunta vai ficar aqui simplesmente perdida (já que o AP não pareceu mais pra responder aos comentários, a pergunta é realmente ampla e genérica, e a resposta existente é pouco útil pro AP e pra qualquer outro leitor futuro).

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando C você pode estudar a biblioteca OpenCV, muito utilizada para processamento de imagens.

Este tipo de padrão que você deseja detectar envolve técnicas como Feature Detection e um bom conhecimento em normalização de imagens.

O entendimento de algoritmos de visão computacional como este que você deseja implementar requer muito estudo e dedicação.

A documentação e download do OpenCV podem ser encontrados nos seguintes links:

[Downloads](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)

[Documentação](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/index.html)

Espero ter ajudado.